# WP Custom field display on "php if" variable with another element

Tags: field

I’m trying to display a custom field in Wordpress, from the advanced custom field plugin… a summary of the review on pages that include a review box in my posts.

There's a checkbox when creating a post with my theme for "this post is a review" and then adds the review box at the bottom. The bit of code that includes the review box if it is checked while making the post looks like this (from single.php file):

```
<?php $result_cmb_is_review = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cmb_is_review', true);
if ($result_cmb_is_review == 'checked')
{include 'inc/template_review.php';
}
?>
```

I’d like to add this code for a summary box beside the review box in the post:

```
<h3><?php _e(‘Summary’); ?></h3>
<p><?php get_field( 'review_summary' ); ?></p>
```

(unless there’s a better way of displaying the ACF field)

But I only want the Summary field to show up if the post is checked to be a review. I'm also looking to just include the content from the custom field on that particular post...not universal content shown in all the review posts.

I can’t seem to figure out how to get both the review box/template and the custom field to show up only if the review is checked. It's frustrating because I've tried multiple combinations from searching through forums. All they seem to do is wreck the page (refresh, white page) and it seems my limited php knowledge is the only thing holding back finally launching my site.

I've posted in a few different "support" areas but of course not even a response. Any tips would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to using the ACF functions to get the value of the custom fields as opposed to wordpress just for consistency. In the code below we check to see if cmb_is_view has a value, and if it does we will first include your template review script, then we will echo out the text 'Summary' wrapped in h3 tags. Next we will echo out the review summary wrapped in p tags.

Keep in mind that get_field('example') does not echo out the contents, so in your original question you would have needed to use: the_field();

```
<p><?php the_field( 'review_summary' ); ?></p>
```

This is the approach I would take however.

```
if ( get_field('cmb_is_review') ) :
     include('inc/template_review.php');
     echo '<h3>;
     _e('Summary');
     echo '</h3>';
     echo '<p>'.get_field('review_summary').'</p>';
endif;
```